# Obtaining applications enlisted in force quit window

Tags: cocoa, nsrunningapplication

I am trying to retrieve all applications which are enlisted in force quit window.

When I am using runningAppications method using below line of code:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
```

It is enlisting many extra applications which are not enlisted in force quit window.

Can any one suggest me some way to achieve it?

Comment: Inspect the array/list of runningApplications. There must be some similarity between the applications those are listed in Force Quit list. You can add a watch to the variable in XCode and add a break point then inspect...

Answer (score 2):

The following array contains the applications listed in the "Force Quit Applications" window:

```
NSArray *apps = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] valueForKeyPath:@"launchedApplications.NSApplicationName"];
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help :-) .. it is working as I expect but it seems to be deprecated in OS X 10.7.. any other alternative solution?

Comment: As far I'm aware the code above is not deprecated, using the 10.7 deployment target I don't get any warning.